# What can I do about a shower valve stem that is too far recessed after tiling?

Tags: shower, valve

I am putting a shower back together after tiling it and putting fixtures back in. I bought a Moen universal shower handle trim kit because it was really the only thing I saw in a metal finish with that worked with a push/pull shower valve.

I no longer have access to the valve itself since dry wall, thinset, kerdi, and more thinset is surrounding the valve stem coming out of the wall. Anyway, it is now too far recessed and the handle has a piece (which I forgot to take a picture) that fits over the stem. It is flat on two sides and fits over it and then screwed into it.

Is there an extension piece that one can buy that will connect the two? Any suggestions would be great that doesn't require opening the wall back up. Just something I didn't think of while I was tiling.

The sleeve coming out of the wall can be pushed in further but it won't do any good. The "arms" on the piece that goes in the handle that prevents the handle from being turned passed the top part of the sleeve will just hit the face plate.

[image: Shower valve stem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Moen knob/stem extensions available. Go to a reputable plumbing shop with your knob and some pictures.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I hadn't run into those yet. Though, considering my wretched experiences with Moen I'm not surprised they have something like this.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Really just need the brass stem piece and Moen is cool enough to send me a couple for free!

Comment: Sweet : ) Free is good!

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, that sucks. **First thought**, put a few small nuts (from bolts, not squirrels) in the handle's hole. **Second thought**, a short chunk of 1/4" pipe (or whatever) & likely a longer handle screw...**more on those below**. **Third thought**, grind that center round collar with the notch at the top down to the screwed-on escutcheon...Though, I think you eluded to that won't work. Which, brings me to my **Fourth thought**, use or try another handle from an old TV, Stove (not seriously, I mean come on what would people think) or of course a Sink Faucet for measurements & go buy a replacement handle to match the measurements.

Anyway, the nuts would only keep the handle from spinning but won't hold up well on the stem end & will eventually loosen, even with lock washers. But, the pipe could be crimped at the ends to fit & lock over the stem beautifully & lock into the handle just as well. The handle side will need some tweaking & maybe even a slit for shrinking.

Of course, the longer screw might still be needed...a screw from a door lockset might be just right in diameter, thread spread & length, if you have any spares around or are going over to the neighbor's for dinner any time real soon. Kidding...I'm just kidding...don't do that to anyone!